# Is there an alternate way to connect a eGPU in another way than using the PCI-E slot?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, graphics-card, hdmi, pci-express

I have an Asus K55VD laptop connected to an external graphic card dock .

I remove the WIFI card and insert a mini PCI-E cable , and on the other side of the cable it has a male HDMI , and it's connected to the Dock

My system looks similar to this

[image]

And this is the cable I'm talking about that connects the computer to the graphic card station

[image]

The system worked fine for 2 years , but my problem is the cable pin seen to be damaged , and it's very hard to find the replacement part in north America

So my big question is ,as my pc is not super old and has HDMI port and some USB 3.0 is there another way to make connect the station to the laptop?
I tried connecting HDMI to HDMI in the past and it didn't work

so far I only found the Expresscard but my laptop don't have ExpressCard slot

Is there another way than having to use an HDMI male output  to Mini PCI-E input ?

Thank you

Comment: No; There is no other way to connect a PCIe card other then to use a PCIe connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use HDMI to plug an external GPU.

The only way (aside mini pcie and expresscard) is thunderbolt enabled solutions, yet none of them are available for end users..